# JavaFX and Spring - beans doesn't Autowire

Tags: java, spring, javafx

I have problems with combining JavaFX and Spring. I have simple JavaFX application, which works fine. Now I am trying to add some Spring to it. I followed [JavaFX 2 with Spring Tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/03/javafx-2-with-spring.html). My code:

```
src/main
|
|_java/mycompany/imageviewer
|   |
|   |_Startup.java
|   |_controller/ImageViewController.java
|   |_dataprovider
|       |impl/DataProviderImpl.java
|   |_config
|       |_SpringFxmlLoader.java
|       |_SpringApplicationConfig.java
|_resources/mycompany/view/ImageViewer.fxml
```

`Startup.java` is file with main:

```
public class Startup extends Application {

    private static final SpringFxmlLoader loader = new SpringFxmlLoader();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ...    
        Parent root = (Parent) loader.load("/mycompany/imageviewer/view/ImageViewer.fxml","mycompany/imageviewer/bundle/bundle");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        ...css etc...
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

`ImageviewerController.java`:

```
@Controller
public class ImageViewerController {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ImageViewerController.class);
    @FXML
    ...    
    @Autowired
    private DataProvider dataProvider;

    public ImageViewerController() {
        LOG.debug("Controller initialized. DataProvider is null: "+(dataProvider==null));
    }
```

`DataProviderImpl.java`:

```
@Service("dataProvider")
public class DataProviderImpl implements DataProvider {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(DataProviderImpl.class);

    public DataProviderImpl() {
        LOG.debug("DataProviderImpl initialized.");
    }
    ...methods...
}
```

My SpringFxmlLoader looks similar to this in tutorial:

```
public class SpringFxmlLoader {

    private static final ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringApplicationConfig.class);

    public Object load(String url, String resources) {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setControllerFactory(clazz -> applicationContext.getBean(clazz));
        try {
            return loader.load(getClass().getResource(url), ResourceBundle.getBundle(resources));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

My SpringApplicationConfig:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"mycompany.imageviewer.controller", "mycompany.imageviewer.dataprovider.impl" })
public class SpringApplicationConfig {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(SpringApplicationConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public DataProvider dataProvider() {
        LOG.debug("Initializing dataProvider via SpringApplicationConfig");
        return new DataProviderImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public ImageViewerController imageViewerController() {
        LOG.debug("Initializing ImageViewerController via SpringApplicationConfig");
        return new ImageViewerController();
    }
}
```

In my app I have `ImageViewer.fxml` with binded controller:

```
<AnchorPane fx:controller="mycompany.imageviewer.controller.ImageViewerController" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.51" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" >
```

When I run program I get logs:

```
DEBUG [main] mycompany.imageviewer.controller.ImageViewerController:74 - Controller initialized. DataProviderImpl is null: true
DEBUG [main] mycompany.imageviewer.dataprovider.impl.DataProviderImpl:22 - DataProviderImpl initialized.
DEBUG [JavaFX Application Thread] mycompany.imageviewer.controller.ImageViewerController:74 - Controller initialized. DataProviderImpl is null: true
```

Which shows, that my controller is initialized twice, and the `dataProvider` is not properly binded. What made me confused, was that when I accidentaly wrote wrong `basePackages` in `ComponentScan` in this way with wrong packages:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"mycompany.imageviewer.dataprovider.controller", "mycompany.imageviewer.dataprovider.dataprovider.impl" })
```

Beans initialize methods in `SpringApplicationConfig.java` run and I get logs from them:

```
2015-09-06 16:52:29,420 DEBUG [main] com.capgemini.starterkit.imageviewer.config.SpringApplicationConfig:19 - Initializing dataProvider via SpringApplicationConfig
2015-09-06 16:52:29,431 DEBUG [main] com.capgemini.starterkit.imageviewer.dataprovider.impl.DataProviderImpl:22 - DataProviderImpl initialized.
DEBUG [main] mycompany.imageviewer.config.SpringApplicationConfig:25 - Initializing ImageViewerController via SpringApplicationConfig
DEBUG [main] mycompany.imageviewer.controller.ImageViewerController:74 - Controller initialized. DataProviderImpl is null: true
DEBUG [JavaFX Application Thread] mycompany.imageviewer.controller.ImageViewerController:74 - Controller initialized. DataProviderImpl is null: true
```

When I run `basePackages = "com.capgemini.starterkit.imageviewer"` effect is the same like in the first case.
I am new to spring and probably I made some simple mistakes, but I am not able to find them, so if anybody can help me configure spring that would be great.:-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`FXMLLoader.load(URL, ResourceBundle)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#load-java.net.URL-java.util.ResourceBundle-) method you are calling is a `static` method - so it actually pays no attention to the `FXMLLoader` instance you instantiated, and consequently ignores the `controllerFactory` which references your Spring bean factory.

Rewrite your `SpringFXMLLoader` class as follows:

```
public class SpringFxmlLoader {

    private static final ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringApplicationConfig.class);

    public Object load(String url, String resources) {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setControllerFactory(clazz -> applicationContext.getBean(clazz));
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource(url));
        loader.setResources(ResourceBundle.getBundle(resources));
        try {
            return loader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This uses the *instance* method [`loader.load()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#load--) which will use your controller factory: i.e. it will use Spring to instantiate the controller.

The reason you see the controller loaded twice is that by default the bean factory gives the controller singleton scope and makes it eagerly created, so as soon as you create the bean factory (`applicationContext`) it creates a controller. That controller will have its `dataProvider` initialized (but only *after* the constructor has completed, of course). Then the call to the static `FXMLLoader.load(...)` method creates a second controller by the usual mechanism (i.e. by calling its no-arg constructor). That instance will not have its `dataProvider` initialized at any time.

As an aside, you probably don't want controllers to be singletons. If you were to load your FXML file twice, to get two instances of the `Parent`, you would likely need each instance to have its own controller, otherwise strange behavior would ensue. I would recommend making the controller a prototype (which means the bean factory will create a new instance every time one is requested, instead of reusing a single instance). You can do this with the following in your config class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"mycompany.imageviewer.controller", "mycompany.imageviewer.dataprovider.impl" })
public class SpringApplicationConfig {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(SpringApplicationConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public DataProvider dataProvider() {
        LOG.debug("Initializing dataProvider via SpringApplicationConfig");
        return new DataProviderImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public ImageViewerController imageViewerController() {
        LOG.debug("Initializing ImageViewerController via SpringApplicationConfig");
        return new ImageViewerController();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer solved my problem. But I have to admmit, that I am not understanding your last paragraph, but I understand that the fact that I shouldn't use my `ImageViewerController` as bean. Could you explain what is the good solution of this problem, please?

Comment: I'm not saying you shouldn't use it as a bean, just that you shouldn't let it have singleton scope. Singleton scope means the bean factory will return the same instance every time one is requested: you (almost certainly) want a new instance each time one is requested. To do this, just make it a `prototype` scope: see updated answer.