# JavaFX and Spring: issue with autowiring

Tags: java, spring, javafx, spring-boot

I am trying to use JavaFX and Spring together. I am using Spring Boot, in particular.
My issue is that I have both Spring autowired fields and JavaFX "autowired" fields in the FXML controller.
I put a breakpoint in the constructor controller and it is actually being invoked twice: one by Spring, which autowires `@Autowired` fields only, one by JavaFX, which initialize `@FXML` fields only.

Here's my main code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MySpringAndJavaFXApp extends AbstractJavaFXAndSpringApplication {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage window) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/home.fxml"));
        window.setTitle("My Title");
        window.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 300));
        window.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
       launchApp(MySpringAndJavaFXApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here's the class I am extending:

```
public abstract class JavaFXAndSpringApplication extends Application {

    protected static void launchApp(Class<? extends JavaFXAndSpringApplication> classePrincipaleJavaFX, String[] args) {
        launch(classePrincipaleJavaFX,args);
    }

    private ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(getClass());
        applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        super.stop();
        applicationContext.close();
    }
}
```

An example of a class being Spring-managed and JavaFX-managed:

```
@Component
public class MixedController {

    @FXML
    private TextField aTextField;

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService; // MyService is a @Component


    public MixedController() {
        System.out.println("I am here"); // debugger goes twice here
    }
}
```

How I can easily fix my issue?
I attempted using a custom FXML loader (e.g. [JavaFX and Spring - beans doesn't Autowire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32424878/javafx-and-spring-beans-doesnt-autowire)). However, if I load the home.fxml file with such loader, I get an error on the data provider (i.e. Spring is not getting my database configuration correctly) and I would prefer another approach.

Comment: Check [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32426672/2747533) to the question you've linked to. Use an instance of `FXMLLoader`, don't load with static method.

Comment: Yes, that's what I tried (see my OP last lines) and couldn't get it to work.

Comment: In `MySpringAndJavaFXApp` at first line of the `start` method a static `load` method is being called. Either your sample code is wrong or you are calling a static method. Initialize `FXMLoader` and pass `ControllerFactory` to it as described in discussed answer.

Comment: The code I posted does not refer to the attempt of using the custom FXMLLoader. I haven't reported that attempt. I would prefer not using a custom FXMLLoader, if there is another approach (it causes me several issues). Does it exist?

Comment: @Manu You don't have to use a *custom* `FXMLLoader`. Just create a `FXMLLoader` instance and set the controller factory on it. As stated above, don't use the static method.

Comment: The bottom line here is that if you want Spring to create the controllers that are used by the `FXMLLoader` you *must* set a controller factory on the `FXMLLoader` (and of course to do that, you must have an `FXMLLoader` instance). If you don't set a controller factory, the `FXMLLoader` will create a new instance of the controller class. The issue with the database configuration sounds like another issue entirely.

Comment: Ok, I got the point. Is there a way to go the other way round and automatically register a fxcontroller as a spring bean?

Comment: Checkout the github projects: `jacpfx` or `easyfxml`. They both facilitate interop between javafx and spring. EasyFXML is probably all you need tbh